# modify the target page

Tags: c#, windows-phone

So i have a longlistselector (in main) with items, and a "Detail-page" (panorama page) where i want to display more information about that spezific item. how can i "pass" the information, what item was clicked and what in the Detail page should be loaded?
so maybe the code:

in the main i have

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    //...
    public int ID = 0; //wrong, because my idea is false i guess

    //...


public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //...


private void example_Tap(object sender, EventArgs e) //example_tap is the eventhandler 
                                                     //when i tap an item on the longlistselector
    {
      //...

     var tb = sender as TextBlock;

     if (tb != null)
        {
            if (tb.Text == "Text of the first item in my list")
            {
                ID = 1; // My idea is to "pass" this int to the other page, 
                        // so i know what info to load
            }

            if (tb.Text == "Text of the second item in my list")
            {
                ID = 2;
            }
        //...and so on
        }  
    else
        {
            return;
        }      

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Detailpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

then on the Detailpage i want to have something like this (it is a new class of course and that is my problem)

```
 public partial class PanoramaPage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {

    public PanoramaPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //...



    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    ...
    if (ID == 1)
        {
            MyClass.LoadData_1(); // this loads information, 
                                  // that should "modify" the detailpage...

        }

    if (ID == 2)
        {
           MyClass.LoadData_2(); //in case, that the second item was tapped, 
                                 //the page should be filled with this information
        }

    //... and so on

    }
  }
```

so how can i do this?
thanks a lot. sry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use parameters on the URL, add at the end of the URL something like:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Detailpage.xaml?ID=" + ID.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

Then retrieve it with

```
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ID", out ID);
```

Comment: thx! was sitting the whole yesterday evening trying to get this done. should have posted it earlier, now it works. :)